# Help following a published calculation of a prediction confidence interval for a prediction made from a simple ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, confidence-interval

I'm trying to follow a calculation made in a paper(section 2 from the supplementary contents of `Likelihood based observability analysis and confidence intervals for predictions of dynamic models. Kreutz C, Raue A and Timmer J. BMC Systems Biology 6, 120, 2012`) for determining a $prediction$ confidence interval (PCI) for a prediction made from a very simple differential equation.

Before diving into the specifics  I wanted to briefly give you the background of the calculation. Also, thank you in advance for reading though and sticking with the problem.

------------------------The bit I understand ------------------

The ODE in question:

$[1]$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-θ$$

where $x(0)=1$, we have a single data point $y=0.9$ for $x$ at time point $t=1$ (with assumed Gaussian measurement noise $N(0,0.1^2)$.

The solution to this equation is:

$[2]$

$$ x(t)=-exp(-θt)      $$

The log-likelihood is:

$[3]$

$$ LL(y|θ)=log[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2*pi*sigma^2}}exp(\frac{-0.9 - exp(-θ))^2}{2*sigma^2})] $$

$[4]$

$$=-50(0.9-exp(-θ))^2+c $$

Where $ c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2*pi*sigma^2}}$

The maximum likelihood estimate is obtained by:

$[5]$

$$\frac{\partial{LL(y|θ)}}{\partial{θ}}=0 $$

They then analytically derive that the $θ$ estimate $θhat$ is:

$$-log(0.9)=0.1054 $$

-------------The bit I don't understand----------

I now understand how the above was obtained thanks to a previous question I asked on this site. Now I need to understand the next bit - which is predicting the confidence intervals assuming the desired prediction is given by $z=θ^2$

$[6]$

$$ \{z(θ)|LL(y|θ) <= LL(y|θhat) + icdf(chisq_1,alpha)\}$$

(that is `<=` is smaller than or equal to and `icdf(chisq_1,alpha)` is the alpha quantile of the chi squared distribution with 1 degrees of freedom (which is 3.8415) .

They now say: `For the boundaries of the parameter confidence interval it holds:`

$[7]$
$$ LL(y|θ) = LL(y|θhat) + icdf(chisq_1,alpha) $$

$question 1$: Why does it hold? Have they derived this from some theorem I'm currently unaware of or is it derived from these calculations? Should I just take this as fact?

`if and only if`

$[8]$

$$ 50(0.9-exp(-θ))^2 + c = c + 3.8415 $$

$Question2$: clearly they have substituted the log likelihood function on the left here, but how has the estimated version on the right now become `c`?

And this `implies` that:

$[9]$

$ θ=-0.1631$ or $θ = 0.4734$

$Question3:$ how have they arrived to these figures? Substituting the calculated $θ$ estimate does not work and neither does canceling $c$ and solving for $θ$

Therefore, they have calculated that the $parameter$ confidence interval is $θ $ in the set $[-0.1631,0.4734]$. They then go on to say that the $prediction$ confidence interval for the $z=θ^2$ is $z$ in the set $[0,0.2241]$.

$Question 4:$ How have they used the $parameter$ confidence interval to calculate the $prediction$ confidence internal?